# How to start/stop FFMPEG stream?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, java-native-interface, rtsp

I am using ip cam which provides streams mov/mp4. I am successfully saving the stream using this command: 
`ffmpeg -i rtsp://@192.168.241.1:62156/abc.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy c:/abcd.mp4`

Now I want to stop it programmatically for that I used following commands:
`Ctrl+C` and `q` both are working fine(logs are showing in right manner) but in the end I am getting corrupt video file.

Can any one guide me how can stop recording with clean execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be it will be helpful for someone so I am positing here my solution.

After few search I found that files are corrupted because here are I am interrupting to finish the mp4 encode, so I switched to something like `mkv` and it worked perfectly.
This is the command I am using now:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://@192.168.241.1:62156/abc.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy c:/abcd.mkv
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following for MP4

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://@192.168.241.1:62156/abc.mp4 -c copy -movflags +empty_moov+separate_moof abcd.mp4
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://@192.168.241.1:62156/abc.mp4 -c copy abcd.ts
```